# Lotus Notes: Displaying days of a month, following the weekdays of it

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a not so nice question. I've been thinking about this for like a month now and read a couple of books but can seem to find an answer or how to execute this. As you all know, I'm making this application that generates date. I have one combobox it has months in it, starting january to december, two column table, first colum displays the day and the second one displays the weekdays,  on selecting month combobox, it must display the days in that month on first column and weekdays on 2nd column, by row. example: I choose january, on the first column it will display the days of that month, 1st row is 1, 2nd row is 2, and so on, and same as weekdays. I'm kinda new to LN. Can you give me an idea for it? Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution based on Notes @Formula. Only a few lines of code are necessary to achieve the result.

First we need the form

[image]

The formula for `Days` is

```
_days :=1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31;
_numberDays := @Day(@Adjust(@Adjust(@Date(@ToNumber(Year); @ToNumber(Month); 1); 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0); 0; 0; -1; 0; 0; 0));
@Subset(_days; _numberDays)
```

and the formula for `Weekday` is

```
_weekdays := @Transform( @ToNumber(Days); "day"; 
    @Weekday(@Date(@ToNumber(Year); @ToNumber(Month); day)));
@Replace(@Text(_weekdays);
     "1":"2":"3":"4":"5":"6":"7";
    "Sunday":"Monday":"Tuesday":"Wednesday":"Thursday":"Friday":"Saturday")
```

That's it.

The fields `Month` and `Year` have to have the property "Refresh fields on keyword change".

The fields `Days` and `Weekday` need "Computed for display", "Allow multiple values" and "New Line" as separate values.

The result will look like this

[image]

Comment: That's just one table row with 30 lines in it.  I was guessing he wants real table rows so he can have additional fields.  But yes, this is an elegant solution.

Comment: @Richard: Yeah, but even if it is necessary to have every day in a single table row the hard work is done. Create a row for every day, write in e.g. row 28th the text `28` in first column, put field `Weekday28` with formula `Weekday[28]` in second column and set the "hide when" formula for complete row to `!(Days = 28)` (only for rows 28 to 31). Fields `Days` and `Weekday` have to be hided in this scenario.

Comment: Hello Knut! Got your solution working. Thanks alot! But as Richard said, how can I put them in a table rows? Sorry for such question.

Comment: I tried the Weekday[28] and so on, but it only accept Weekday[1], when I put a higher number, it says, index array out of bounds.

Comment: Then your Weekday- Field is not Multi- Value (property "Allow multiple values" not ticked...

Comment: Tode is right, please set "Allow multiple values" property for field `Weekday`. In addition, use as formula for `Weekday28` from  row 28 `@If(Days=28;Weekday[28];"")` or `@Subset(@Subset(Weekday;28);-1)`. After changing this is it working for you?

Comment: wow! thanks you guys. I got it working now. Thanks again, you're a really great help Knut.

Answer (score 1):

Truly dynamic tables are difficult. In this case it's definitely possible because you have a defined number of rows, but it's still somewhat messy.

I'm not aware of anything built in that will easily tell you how many days there are in each month.  I'd probably just create a config doc with year, month, and numberOfDays fields, and hidden view that you can use for lookups.  You're going to need this in many places, and you don't want to do the lookup each time, so do it in a hidden computed field that comes after your dropdown but before your table.  (Be sure to set properties so the field is recomputed after the value in the dropdown is changed.)  Call the field something like daysInSelectedMonth.

Obviously the first column is easy: just create your table and enter the numbers 1 through 31, and apply a hide-when formula to the cells for rows 29 through 31 so that they only show up if daysInSelectedMonth is the right number of days. You don't need the hide when in the other rows.

For the second column, you will need to use computed for display fields.  I would strongly suggest naming them something like weekday_1, weekday_2,... weekday_31 so that you can use @ThisName and some simple string manipulation to extract the number from the field name.  That will tell you what row the formula is in, and it is your day number.  The benefit of doing it this way is that your formula can be exactly the same in every one of the fields -- just a cut-and-paste into the other fields after you get it right once.

I would suggest starting to work on the formula in the weekday_31 field, and when you get it right (showing the correct weekday in a month that does have 31 days, and blank in a month that does not), then you can copy the formula to the rest of the fields.  You will need to use an @If to detect whether the month has the correct number of days -- this is easy, except for leap year.  I'm going to leave that part up to you.  Just make it return "" if the month does not have the right number of days, and then have the final clause of the @f use @Date to build the value for the date that you are working on and then use the @Weekday function to display the value.

Comment: Uisng Lotusscript, it is much easier. Just create a date object for start date, another one for end date, add a month and remove one day from the end date, and you can now loop though it. :-)

Comment: Yes, but you're not hiding unused rows. If aesthetics matter, then you will have to use hide-whens for that, so I figured I might as well go with formula language all the way ;-) I forgot the trick of going to the next month and adjusting back one day to get the number of days.

Comment: You can find how many days there are in a month (including leap years) using

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on a few things:
Web application or Notes client application?
What is the end result of the exercise, i.e. what is the table intended to be used for? Display purposes only?

Making some assumptions (Notes client application, and table used only for display), I see two ways to do this.

An easy  way to do this is to create the table with 31 rows and 2 columns.
In the cells you create fields: Day1, Weekday1, Day2, Weekday2, etc.
You also need a year field, unless it is always current year.
Set a hide-when formula on rows 29-31, to hide if the Day field for that row is blank.
On the advanced properties tab for the combobox where you select month, set "Run Exiting/OnChange events after value change".
In the Exiting event for the combobox, write some Lotusscript that populate the fields with days and weekdays, based on selected year and month. Something like this (untested:

```
Sub Exiting(Source As Field)
    Dim session As New NotesSession 
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim monthName As String
    Dim YYYY As String
    Dim firstDate As NotesDateTime 
    Dim lastDate As NotesDateTime 
    Dim n As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dayname(1 To 7) As String

    dayname(1) = "Sunday"
    dayname(2) = "Monday"
    dayname(3) = "Tuesday"
    dayname(4) = "Wednesday"
    dayname(5) = "Thursday"
    dayname(6) = "Friday"
    dayname(7) = "Saturday"
    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    YYYY = uidoc.FieldGetText("Year")
    monthName = uidoc.FieldGetText("Month")
    Set firstDate = New NotesDateTime("1 " & monthName & ", " & YYYY)
    Set lastDate = New NotesDateTime(firstDate.DateOnly)
    Call lastDate.AdjustMonth(1)
    Call lastDate.AdjustDay(-1)
    i = 0
    For n = Cdbl(firstDate.LSLocalTime) To Cdbl(lastDate.LSLocalTime)
        i = i + 1
        Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Day" & i, Cstr(i))
        Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Weekday" & i, dayname(Weekday(Cdat(n))))
    Next
    Call uidoc.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a truly dynamic table, is the method I blogged about here:
http://blog.texasswede.com/dynamic-tables-in-classic-notes/

The benefit is that it is more flexible, and you can create a nicer layout without needing to create a large number of fields.